# How to extract a method to a separate class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a method which accesses many fields, so it’s hard coded into its class. I would like to make it reusable by other classes.

Is there any way of getting a list of all fields and methods (within the same class) that a method accesses?

I’m using VS2010.

Comment: One very quick and dirty way is to mark the method as static and look at the compiler errors.

Comment: You can view the Call Hierarchy to see what other methods a method calls; I'm not sure if there's anything similar for fields.

Comment: @DanBryant: May not work if it wants to access static members...

Comment: ReSharper can do this sort of thing easily, using the "Make Method Static" refactoring.

Comment: You could make an interface that defines the overlapping properties and the method. Then every class using the method would implement the Interface. Or make an abstract class, there you can define the method so every inheriting class can use the method.

There is no way to "ask" the method what fields it uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, take that method out of the class and put it into an empty class and try to compile. Compiler will complain about a list of fields that this method wants to access but could not find.

Answer (score 0):

The Reflection namespace can do just about anything you'd need in this regard. Specifically, I think you'll want to check out System.Reflection.PropertyInfo and System.Reflection.MemberInfo.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it. I have: `Type t = typeof(Form1);           MethodInfo mi = t.GetMethod("method1");
mi.`

 And I can’t find the next step. What now?